# Map extension in linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $W$ be a subspace of $V$. If $T:W \to U$ is a linear map for some vector space $U$ over $F$ then how to prove there exists a linear map $S:V \to U$ such that $S(w)=T(w)$ for every $w \in W$?

Anyone can tell how to prove this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I took dimV is n and dimW is m since W is subspace of V so dimW is less than dimV so took basis of W extended to basos of V. Also as T is linear so  for every u in U there exist w in W s.t. u = T (w) . S is also linear so for every u in U there is v in V  s.t. S(v)= u . Which give S(v) = T(w) for every w in W .

Comment: @Shona What you have written doesn't make sense. First of all, the statement "for every $u \in U$ there is some $w \in W$ such that $T(w) = u$ is the statement that $T$ is onto, not that $T$ is linear. You are not assuming that $T$ is onto in this question. Secondly, you can't conclude that $S(v) = T(w)$ for every $w \in W$ because $w$ *depends* on which $u$ we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea of what you can do. Find a complementary subspace $W'$ to $W$ in $V$, i.e. a subspace of $V$ such that $V = W \oplus W'$. Then every vector in $V$ can be written uniquely as $w + w'$ for some $w \in W$ and some $w' \in W'$. Therefore we can define $S(w+w') = T(w)$. You can check for yourself that this map is well-defined, linear, and that it extends $T$.

Comment: How u said i did like ;;;   T:W->U is defined as T(w)= u and S :V-> U defined as S(v)=u where v= w+w'         to prove well defined :  let u1=u2  , u1,u2 belong to U     then        T(w1)=T(w2) ,   w1,w2 belong to W and  for w' belong to W'       then  as we defined we have   S(w1+w')=S(w2+w')  according to definition S(v1)=S(v2)  for  v= w+w' belong to V ... now to prove linear    S is linear  Let S (av1+bv2)= S(a(w1+w')+b(w2+w')) = T(aw1+bw2) = aT(w1)+bT(w2) = aS(v1)+bS(v2) ...   but how being well defined and linear  make S extend T ??